# Out of memory exception in Hosted server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core, out-of-memory

Is there any way to configure a server for debugging application in Visual Studio?

I'm using .NET Core 2.1 MVC

My problem the project was published and uploaded to the server but randomly Getting `System.OutOfMemoryException`. I didn't catch the areas. The areas are also random. I don't know what is the problem is. In our staging server, it is working fine and there are no exceptions. The client-server is Azure

App Service Configuration

- P1V2 1core
- 3.5GB RAM
- 250GB Storage space

Is there any option to create a server same as this configuration and debug in Visual Studio ?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: By the way, NET Core 2.0 is out of support https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0

Comment: @PauloMorgado its windows OS and I am using .net core 2.1 Updated the question

Comment: You need to create a memory dump to see how your memory is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/how-to-get-a-full-memory-dump-in-azure-app-services